# Double integral problem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm given that 
$$
f(x,y)= \cases{
 \left(y-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(x-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{-3} &  \text{if } \left|y-\tfrac{1}{2}\right|<\left|x-\tfrac{1}{2}\right|
\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
}
$$

I want to find the double integrals $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dx\;dy$$ and $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left \lvert f(x,y)\right \rvert\,dx\;dy.$$

I've tried splitting each integral up into two integrals where the outer integral goes from $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$ and from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $1$. But, I am having trouble determining what the inner integral bounds should be.

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram of the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so hard as we're interested only in $\;x,y>0\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}&x,y\ge\frac12\implies y-\frac12<x-\frac12\implies y<x\\{}\\&0<x<\frac12\;,\;\;y\ge\frac12\;\implies\;y-\frac12<\frac12-x\implies y\le-x+1\\{}\\&0<x,y<\frac12\;\implies\;\frac12-y<\frac12-x\implies y>x\\{}\\&x\ge\frac12\,,\,0<y<\frac12\;\implies\;\frac12-y<x-\frac12\implies y>-x+1\end{align*}$$

Draw the above lines that determine the integration domain, and then we get:

$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1 f(x,y)\,dxdy=\int\limits_0^{1/2}\int\limits_x^{-x+1} f(x,y) \,dydx+\int\limits_{1/2}^1\int\limits_{-x+1}^x f(x,y)\,dydx$$

Comment: Double check your last inequality calc. For the second integral, the limits of integration should be from $y = 1-x$ to $y = x$. It's a curious region.

Comment: So to find the double integral of $|f(x,y)|$, I will need to have 4 integrals overall (two for each of the two integrals above) to get rid of the the absolute values?

Comment: @SimonS, indeed. After all those calculations I missed those different signs of $\;\frac12\;$ on different sides. Thanks, editing.

Comment: @user190961, not necessarily but perhaps. You have to find out about the sign ofthe function on each piece of the integration domain.

Comment: I guess I am still confused about the double integral of |f(x,y)|. When $x$ is between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$,  $|x-\frac{1}{2}|^3 =(\frac{1}{2}-x)^3$, but $y$ is between $x$ and $1-x$, and so I cannot just write $|y-\frac{1}{2}|$ as $y-\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{2}-y$, but I don't see how to split the integral up further to account for this.

Comment: Well, that's precisely what you should have realized by your own:$$\int\limits_0^{1/2}\int\limits_x^{-x+1} \left|f\right|\,dydx=\int\limits_0^{1/2}dx\left(\int\limits_x^{1/2}\frac{\frac12-y}{\left(\frac12-x\right)^3}dy+\int\limits_{1/2}^{-x+1}\frac{y-\frac12}{\left( \frac12-x\right)^3}dy\right)$$and like wise the other one mutatis mutandi

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)= \cases{
 (y-\tfrac{1}{2})(x-\tfrac{1}{2})^{-3}, & \text{if } |y-\tfrac{1}{2}|<|x-\tfrac{1}{2}|
\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
}$$

Note that $|y-\tfrac{1}{2}|<|x-\tfrac{1}{2}|$ is true for: 
$$0 \leq x<1/2,\quad   x<y<1-x$$
or
$$1/2<x\leq1,\quad   1-x<y<x $$

Thus,
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_0^{0.5}dx\int_x^{1-x}dy\,f(x,y) + \int_{0.5}^{1}dx\int_{1-x}^{x}dy\,f(x,y),$$

and similarly

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1|f(x,y)|\,dx\,dy = \int_0^{0.5}dx\int_x^{1-x}dy\,|f(x,y)| + \int_{0.5}^{1}dx\int_{1-x}^{x}dy\,|f(x,y)|.$$